# Jupyter no funciona en Fedora 26

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, jupyter, fedora

Estoy utilizando la reciente versión de fedora (26), y todo muy bien con Python3, funciona al perfección el "Scipy stack" con los comandos de fedora he podido instalar y utilizar numpy, pandas, etc.
El problema está en que instalé Jupyter con el comando:

```
dnf install notebook
```

Y se tardó un momento (como las otras bibliotecas matemáticas), y me señaló un éxito al finalizar, pero cuando escribo

```
jupyter notebook
```

La terminal me dice:

```
bash: jupyter: command not found
```

Reinicié la terminal y el sitema operativo, y lo mismo, intenté instalar de nuevo Jupyter pero me dice que ya existe y no hay nada que hacer.

¿Alguien sabe qué se puede hacer para usar Jupyter en Fedora 26?

Comment: Supongo que te has equivocado al escribir esto: `dnf install notebook`, debería ser `jupyter`. De todas formas ¿se puede instalar con _dnf_?  Por lo que veo buscando un poco por internet se usa _pip_ o _Anaconda_ para instalarlo.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que se llama `notebook` ese paquete? Aquí lo veo como [`python-notebook`](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/rpms/python-notebook/).